# Diferença entre o uso de struct e classe para criar um objeto

Tags: java, c, orientação-a-objetos, struct

Já havia "aprendido" orientação a objetos na faculdade, bem por cima mesmo.
Agora que comecei a revisar percebi que por mais que digam que `structs` não formam objetos, eu realmente não vejo diferenças entre criar um objeto usando um construtor e uma `struct` usando `typedef`.

Qual a diferença entre isso:

```
//construtor em java
class objeto{
    String nome;
}
//...
novo_objeto = new objeto();
```

e isso?

```
//struct em C
typedef struct
{
   char nome[30];
}objeto;
//...
objeto novo_objeto;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existem algumas questões e premissas erradas aí. E vou desconsiderar a sintaxe errada do Java e tudo estar fora de padrão.

Você não pode fazer uma avaliação das diferenças só pela sintaxe, e em casos tão simples. Vamos dizer que não tivesse diferença nesse caso, teria em casos mais complexos.

O que escreveu em Java não é um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101), é só uma classe muito simples que tem uma série de implicações que nem tem ideia e não acho que valha a pena falar em detalhes aqui.

Você não está vendo mas existe um controle de acesso ao dado e o campo em Java não pode ser acessado por toda aplicação escrito assim, apenas no pacote atual, por padrão um dado é restrito ao pacote. Em C o dado é sempre acessível por toda aplicação.

A mais importante diferença é que uma classe em Java só pode ser alocada no *heap*, enquanto que uma `struct` em C é alocada por padrão na *stack*, podendo alocar no *heap* se necessário, o consumidor tem o controle disso. Se quiser entender mais do assunto já tem pergunta aqui: [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

É até outra questão, por isso não vou detalhar mais, mas em Java essa classe tem só um ponteiro e um outro objeto `String` separado será alocado em outro lugar. Em C a forma que usou está fazendo a *string* ser alocada na própria estrutura.

Em Java o dado é inicializado adequadamente, em C não é, o código tem que fazer isso. Não é que isso estritamente seja OOP, mas é diferente. Note que mesmo não tendo criado um construtor explicitamente no código você só pode criar o objeto chamando um que o compilador criou para você. Em C você não cria um objeto, na verdade o que fez ali foi só reservar memória para o objeto, mais nada.

## Orientação a objeto

Na verdade essa coisa de orientação a objetos é muito mais complexa que isso, e achar que uma classe é OO é um erro. Se [começar a ler sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos?tab=Votes) (tem muita coisa pra ler, não basta ler uma ou outra coisa) verá que está longe de entender o que é OOP e talvez tenha aprendido errado desde o começo (pelo menos é o que indica a pergunta). Nenhum problema, quase todo mundo aprende e faz errado a vida toda, OOP é mais difícil do que as pessoas acham, e justamente por acharem fácil tendem a não aprender certo, tá aí uma boa oportunidade para você começar certo.

De maneira alguma o que está fazendo em Java pode ser considerado um código OO, é só uma estrutura de dados muito simples que cria um tipo (o padrão do Java é sempre criar um tipo, não precisa de `typedef`, nem C++ precisa) que por acaso está encapsulada em uma classe, só isso.

Orientação a objeto é sobre a semântica que quer dar ao objeto e o que ele faz. Você lê esse código e não sabe nada sobre ele, não serve para nada útil, não sabemos sobre o que esse objeto é. Isso é importante para OOP. O máximo que está vendo aí é um mecanismo de classe sendo usado de forma muito simples.

Um dos maiores erros que as pessoas fazem aprendendo OOP é usar exemplos artificiais, só ensina errado porque fala do mecanismo, que não é o importante. OOP serve para ter a complexidade do problema melhor administrada, que só pode ser feito com um exemplo concreto real.

O exemplo é tão ruim que não dá para mostrar outras diferenças, se tivesse um método nele então já daria para mostrar algo, se tivesse especificação de visibilidade, quem sabe herança, polimorfismo, essas outras coisas mostrariam diferenças porque essas coisas começam mostrar visivelmente a orientação a objeto. Se tivesse algo a mais você poderia mostrar algo assim em Java:

```
novo_objeto.fazAlgo();
```

E em C:

```
fazAlgo(novo_objeto);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/Object.java).

Parece bobo mais é importante porque o objeto está em destaque e facilita alguma coisa em Java. Isso é só sintaxe OOP, é uma diferença visível, mas não é como se faz OOP. Inclusive tem linguagem que permite essa sintaxe mesmo nada sendo OO.

A grosso modo OO é colocar tudo o que pertence ao objeto junto dele, é promover o reuso, tentar reproduzir o objeto do mundo real no código. Não concordo muito com essas afirmações que sempre fazem, mas é um passo na direção certa, mesmo que não acerte o alvo fica perto, no momento está indo na direção oposta achando que simplesmente a classe diz o que OOP é.

## Conclusão

Esqueça tudo o que sabe de OOP, até porque disse que não sabe, procure um bom livro sobre o assunto para aprender passo a passo o que é esse paradigma (e procure ler o que *linkei* e outras fontes, porque muitas vão ensinar errado, já que o autor aprendeu errado, porque tem muito material errado por aí, é um telefone sem fio sem fim), tem bastante coisa boa ali sobre o assunto, não digo que é a melhor forma de aprender, mas vai dando informações que levam pro caminho certo de entender que OOP não é só o jeito de usar uma estrutura de dados muito simples. E não esquece de ver outros conceitos mais importantes até antes de OOP.

Comment: ok,  muito obrigado.

Comment: Eu não entendo o porque do negativo na resposta, a resposta me parece que responde as diferenças e ainda fala de algo importante, as pessoas pensam que sabem OOP, mas na maioria aprendeu errado e é importante explicar que isto deve ser aprendido de forma correta. Não é só usar por usar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento talvez pq escrevi correndo :) melhorei. Ou porque a pessoa acha que OOP é a classe. Ou porque falei algo sobre OOP que a pessoa não gostou, mesmo não estando errado. Ou pq eu não expliquei o que é o certo, mesmo a pergunta não sendo sobre isso. Sempre pode ser um voto de alguém que não gosta de mim, mas eu acho que nem foi o caso. Se ela comentasse ajudaria muito e poderíamos saber e eu poderia melhorar a resposta, eu não tenho compromisso com o erro, talvez essa pessoa tenha. Eu posso consertar o que está errado e todos ganhamos.

Comment: Não fui eu quem havia negativado, mas confesso que, para mim, a resposta antes de ser editada tinha o defeito de se focar mais nos erros da pergunta do que no conceito de OOP. Mas depois da edição, a resposta tem o selo de qualidade Maniero e é, como muitas outras, impecável. +1.

Comment: @v.Santos Note que eu mudei muito o pouco o conteúdo e o foco, apenas destaquei mais esse foco e deixei algumas coisas mais claras. Nem acho impecável não, eu não achei das melhores, acho que posso fazer melhor, mas nem tanto porque acho que a pergunta não ajuda muito :) Percebi que deu positivo e por isso não poderia ter dado negativo. Depois fiz uma análise maior e está parecendo que foi negativo por birra com um caso recente que aconteceu. ;)

Comment: @Maniero, a primeira resposta, exceto o ponto que eu apontei anteriormente, estava boa. E eu honestamente admiro a sua paciência em escrever (e reescrever) respostas bem elaboradas mesmo quando a pergunta não ajuda muito. Quanto a "birra por um caso recente", se você estiver se referindo a pergunta sobre a quantidade de linguagens C :) - eu pretendo insistir até a morte que C++ e C# têm esse nome por falta de coragem dos seus criadores em usar o nome D - mas eu acho que você não deveria se preocupar muito com isso já que eu entendi e concordei em parte com a sua crítica e não guardo rancor :).

Comment: @v.Santos eu arrumo birras quase diariamente :D Algumas pessoas gostam do meu estilo, outras não, nunca tentei agradar todos, eu sei quem eu quero agradar e a atitude da pessoa define isso, por sorte agrado essas pessoas ;)

Comment: Eu não negativei também, gostei muito da resposta também