# Abstração de OOP em C

Tags: c, orientação-a-objetos, estilo-de-codificação

Desde que descobri `typedef` e aprendi que uma `struct` é análoga a um objeto, venho pensando em como implementar uma pseudo orientação a objeto em C. Escrevi o seguinte código, que será abstraído do usuário, e que **tenta representar uma classe**. Quero saber se é coerente para fins dessa implementação.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Abstraction
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int (*add)(int, int);
    int (*subtract)(int, int);
    int (*multiply)(int, int);
    int (*divide)(int, int);
} set_t;

set_t * class(int a, int b)
{
    int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
    int subtract(int a, int b)
    {
        return a-b;
    }
    int multiply(int a, int b)
    {
        return a*b;
    }
    int divide(int a, int b)
    {
        return a/b;
    }

    set_t * constructor(int a, int b)
    {
        set_t * this = malloc(sizeof(set_t));
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;

        return this;
    }

    set_t * this = constructor(a, b);

    this->add = add;
    this->subtract = subtract;
    this->multiply = multiply;
    this->divide = divide;

    return this;
}

typedef set_t * set;
//End of abstraction

int main()
{
    set _set = class(3, 5);

    int a = _set->add(3, 5);

    printf("%d %d %d", _set->a, _set->b, a);
}
```

Comment: Não sei em relação à utilidade, mas "normalmente" (não necessariamente normal no C) isto é feito através de VTable, pode ver um exemplo disso em: https://gist.github.com/michahoiting/1aec1c95881881add9a20e9839c35cec

Comment: Amigo, desculpa, mas o que tu queres dizer com "coerente no sentido da utilidade"?

Comment: Útil para o proposto: implementação de OOP em C.

Comment: Relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/q/351733 | https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888

Comment: Já li, ótima recomendação para outros, obrigado @hkotsubo.

Comment: Considere implementar um construtor e um destrutor _dentro_  da classe, bem como o construtor de cópia e movimentação e estará mais perto da noção de objeto. Só implementou métodos em si associados a operações que uma classe pode nem ter. Comece por criar, destruir, copiar e mover. Depois mostrar, como o `toString[]` de java.

Comment: @Inkeliz VTables só vão aparecer no caso de herança ou algum tipo de polimorfismo. Nem toda classe precisa disso e de todo modo ao final da classe postada pelo autor está uma tabela de ponteiros para funções. Só que o V de VTable entraria no caso de implementar classes derivadas.

Answer (score 1):

Bem, a pergunta mudou e agora o foco dele ficou incoerente e não claro, talvez eu não devesse ter respondido. Vou manter porque pode ser útil para o original se alguém quiser saber. De qualquer forma a implementação não guarda estado, que é todo o propósito.

Uma `struct` não é análoga a um [objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101).

Não é coerente no sentido da utilidade (o foco da pergunta). Não houve ganho algum em fazer isso, pelo contrário, ficou ineficiente, vaza memória, tem coisas desnecessárias, não faz sentido e tem conceitos errados e inconsistências de estilo. Sem falar que a sintaxe usada de função aninhada é fora do padrão e não compilará em várias implementações ou opção usada.

Mesmo que queira apenas demonstrar o mecanismo, e não a utilidade falada na pergunta, não é uma forma adequada de fazer.

Se queria apenas criar um mecanismo de [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101), deveria falar sobre isso e não falar de [OOP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108105/101), e usar um exemplo que isso seja necessário. O próprio está errado, de acordo com o padrão comumente implementado, ignorando o `this`. E não há polimorfismo demonstrado também.

Se queria só dar uma sintaxe de chamada da função como se fosse um método, ou seja, chamar a função usando o objeto, cumpriu o papel, mas sem necessidade alguma, até por não ter o `this`.

Não usou herança, [encapsulamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240186/101) de fato (ainda que C não ajude tanto, mas ajuda melhor que isso), e parece que [abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23103/101) não é o que imagina ser.

Primeiro entenda o básico sobre programação, [o que de fato é OOP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101) e ache um exemplo [onde OOP cairia bem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/344486/101). Não use o que não é necessário e não faça o que não entende, entenda antes de fazer. E cuidado com *fake news*, é oque mais tem na internet, e até em alguns livros, especialmente em "programação", o difícil é um ainda leigo separar o joio do trigo para aprender certo. Se treinar o erro é ele que fará a vida toda. Pesquise aqui e outros lugares, tem muito conteúdo para aprender o certo.

Não vou entrar em detalhes porque não é o foco da pergunta e abaixo tem informações adicionais para seguir.

[Pode ver mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80228/101).

[Pode ajudar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/433842/101).

[Implementação de polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101).

Comment: O intuito desse código foi tentar representar uma classe e não todos os conceitos de OOP, não deve ter ficado claro no meu post. Sobre a abstração, não quis colocar à parte o código antes da main para facilitar a minha leitura. Além do mais, se puder explicar as inconsistências de estilo, fico agradecido. Por último, não vejo problema em "explorar" as possibilidades de uma linguagem, não peguei a ideia de um outro lugar, muito menos copiei e colei o código. Agradeço pelas referências, lerei com certeza.

Comment: Não é possível criar classes em C, isso se assemelha a um protótipo.. A pergunta tem um enorme OOP no título e reforçado em comentário. `set` e `set_t` não faz sentido, o que depois obriga usar `_set` que é fora de padrão.